# Simple program not giving output

Tags: java, user-interface, output

I am creating a simple Java application that takes user's monthly wage and weekly hours and calculates how much they make per year and per hour. The gui pops up I input both monthly wage and weekly hours but the output does not give me any figures just you make this much per year press ok and you make this much per hour press ok. Why is there no salary figure output. I am only new to Java since last week. I am not looking for a specific answer in code but more if someone could point me in the right direction as to how I can understand by reading an article on the subject to code it correctly.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WageCal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //declare variables
        int monthlywage;
        int weeklyhours;
        int yearlywage;
        int hourlywage;
        
        //inputs
        monthlywage=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your monthly wage"));
        weeklyhours=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your weekly hours"));
        
        //process
        yearlywage = monthlywage * 12;
        hourlywage = yearlywage / (weeklyhours*52);
        //output 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per year");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per hour"); 
    }
}
```

I am not sure where to start or even the right question to ask

Comment: "*...but the output does not give me any figures just you make this much per year press ok and you make this much per hour press ok. Why is there no salary figure output?*" let me ask counter-question. Since your code responsible for output is `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per year"); JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per hour");` what makes you think values of `yearlywage` or `hourlywage` should be visible?

Comment: You may want to first generate String which will include values you want, like `String ageMessage = "the age is: "+ageVariable;` and then show that message via `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ageMessage);`.

Comment: what makes me think values of yearlywage or hourlywage should be visible is that I have entered both the monthlywage and weeklyhours in the gui and have written the process. Should that not give me my output? I am missing something here

Comment: Code responsible for GUI is only `JOptionPane.showInputDialog(..)` and `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(..)`. Rest happens outside of GUI and that includes *declaration* of `yearlywage` and `hourlywage` and *calculation* its value. But `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per year");` will print only what we told it to, so only `You make this much per year` because that was the only data we gave it. If you want to print other text consider creating String which will hold all data you want to print and use that string as second argument for `showMessageDialog` method.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your output as follows

```
//output
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per year " + yearlywage);
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per hour " + hourlywage);
```

To make it nicer you could use String.format for example. You need to define yourself what the output will be, since you want to display a message followed by the figures, concatenating your String litteral with the appropriate figure will do it.

As for some resources the following may be helpful to you

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html
- https://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_joptionpane.htm

Answer (score 0):

Here's your answer :

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class WageCal {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        //declare variables
        float monthlywage;
        float weeklyhours;
        float yearlywage;
        float hourlywage;
        
        //inputs
        monthlywage=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your monthly wage"));
        weeklyhours=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter your weekly hours"));
        
        //process
        yearlywage = monthlywage * 12;
        hourlywage = yearlywage / (weeklyhours*52);
        //output 
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per year: "+ yearlywage);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You make this much per hour: "+ hourlywage); 
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm .. this is basically the same as the earlier answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75911986/203657 isn't it :)